# PHP Echo not displaying data from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Just working on this little project, and need some help display data in the table.
Tried troubleshooting but am unable to determine why the echo is not displaying data in the table.

It's displaying this instead in the source code:

```
<td><?echo $row['City'];?> </td>
<td><?echo $row['Population'];?> </td>
<td><?echo $row['Country'];?> </td>
<td><?echo $row['Continent'];?> </td>
<td><?echo $row['Region'];?> </td>
```

The result table displayed in the bowser: http://postimg.org/image/sakgymgjv/

Any answer to this is very much appreciated...

Thanks

```
<?  
mysql_connect("localhost", "....", "...") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("world") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "Select a.Name as City, a.Population, b.Name As Country, b.Continent, b.Region from city a LEFT JOIN country b ON a.CountryCode=b.Code";    
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
<table summary="Cities of the world.">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        <th scope="col">Population</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Continent</th>
        <th scope="col">Region</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);)
{   
?>  <td><?echo $row['City'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['Population'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['Country'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['Continent'];?></td>
    <td><?echo $row['Region'];?></td>
<?
}
mysql_close();
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you are viewing the page source of your html page(I mean to say ctrl+u in google chrome) then are you able to see <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>???

Comment: It could be possible that your $row is empty so its not going inside the while loop.

Comment: It's diplaying "<?echo $row['City'];?>", minus the double quotes.

Comment: try to print_r($row) and check if data is correct and you should use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_*

Comment: Remove the extra ; from MYSQL_ASSOC) line and try

Comment: @TBI print_r $row did not display data. Not sure if $row is actually storing any data. But then it displays this "<td><?echo $row['City'];?> </td>" in the source code. Is it just not executing echo??? No idea.

Comment: If $row not displaying data then you should check your query if it is correct...try to run that query in sql server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference, but try taking the ; out of the while loop here:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);)
```

Otherwise check the logs for php and mysql.  Make sure there's not an error.  Also, I'm assuming the database is populated....

Comment: Try removing that ";" did not resolve it. Still not displaying data.

Comment: @Racheal Yep, checked the database, the sql returns records when it's executed using MySql workbench.

Comment: @OmyKaru - In the command line run php -l filenamehere.php  Does it return anything?  If so there's a basic syntax error somewhere.  If php -l runs ok, look inside your php.ini file and look for short_open_tag.  This should be set to true or 1.  If it is not, set it to 1 and restart the web server.

Comment: I am using xampplite appache, where can I be able to run php in cmd. running in the regular command prompt, says "php" is not valid command. Is php a exe file that I should run from the xampplite root folder??

Comment: Ah ok - then you'll want to look for the directory in xamp that contains the php executable via the command line and run it from there (with the full path to your php file such as php c:/path/to/my/file).  If you find the php.exe, you can also set it up in your Windows path so it will find it and can use it globally

Comment: @Racheal Brilliant, got it working when I set short_open_tag on and restarted the appache server..thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect, unless you have shorttags enabled:

`<td><?echo $row['City'];?> </td>` should be `<td><?php echo $row['City'];?> </td>`

Notice the missing `php` from your code. To elaborate, this is what your code should look like:

```
<?php  
mysql_connect("localhost", "....", "...") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("world") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "Select a.Name as City, a.Population, b.Name As Country, b.Continent, b.Region from city a LEFT JOIN country b ON a.CountryCode=b.Code";    
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
```

and

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
?>  <td><?php echo $row['City']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Population']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Country']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Continent']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Region']; ?></td>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Yes. It should be "<? echo" not "<?echo"

Comment: Trying that <td><?php echo $row['City'];?> </td> gave the following error "Notice: Undefined variable: row in ...\index.php on line .."

Comment: You've got a whole host of syntax issues to contend with. Unless you've enabled short tags, you can't use `<?` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

remove the semi-comma in this line

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Comment: Yep tried that also, still displaying the same the heading appear but no data in the table.